# Email Journey to support segmentation, multiple storefront branding themes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, email-template, commerce-cloud

I am currently trying to integrate Marketing Cloud with our website repository to set up automated Abandoned Cart emails.

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to add customized data alongside the Collect Tracking code set-up: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ctc_collect_code.htm&type=5

**Question**:

When integrating the behavioral trigger, behavior tracking code that sends customer data to Marketing Cloud from our website, is it possible to send additional information (custom attributes to what Collect Tracking Code is already collecting), to Marketing Cloud?

And from there, the Marketing Cloud Journey Builder can use that additional information to populate unique store brand information in the email templates.

**Specific use case**:

We currently have multiple storefronts under one website repository that we develop on. A customer can shop in different storefront sites (i.e. brand A, brand B, brand C), but all of those storefront brand sites could contain the same product IDs as other storefront brand sites in the same repository.

**It might not work?**

On the Salesforce documentation for Collect code, it looks like the functionality is limited to preset attributes (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ctc_set_user_info.htm&type=5).

**Has anyone tried:**

Just an idea, is it possible to send in customized attributes like sending in an attribute called, "storefront" when we make the _etmc push for setUserInfo unto Marketing Cloud?

```
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "__________"]);
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "bob@email.com", "storefront": "brand A"}]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is no solution but a hint:

You can define user properties in the tracking call for the user. These are contact attributes. They will be set on the contact profile in einstein for recommendations and even will last forever. YOu cannot delete them only overwrite them, so be careful with your implementation of the user details.

```
  _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {
    "email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID",
    "details": {
      "name": "INSERT_VALUE_HERE",
      "gender": "INSERT_VALUE_HERE",
      "email": "INSERT_VALUE_HERE",
      "location": "INSERT_VALUE_HERE",
      "phone": "INSERT_VALUE_HERE"
    }
  }]);
```

You can write anything in there, it does not need to be name, gender, email, location and phone. It could be storefront or a marketing attribute for the customer. Just be aware that these calls are send in plain text and if a user would analyse the calls that his browser does, he would see the values that you have connected to him.

However you cannot use these attributes to style your emails or use it in journey builder because these attributes are kind of exclusively for rules inside the recommendations. So i believe that you will most likely find no good solution for your case.

Maybe your only option is to create several recommendation sites for each storefront and customize the rules within them. While you send you would need the storefront from your subscriber in your sending dataextension and then have a dynamic content block that references the different recommendations sites.